# How to format the DateTime

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datetime

I am currently looping through a csv file which has numerous dates on various lines, I've managed to split and extract what i want however i have a DateTime format issue. Here is my line of code:

```
current = DateTime.ParseExact(line[0], "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", null);
```

The actual string which is split and read from the csv is:

```
"20/12/2012 13:08:18.980"
```

I am calculating the difference between the two DateTimes (in milliseconds). When I'm debugging and looking at the locals this is what appears for the DateTime "current":

```
 current    {20/12/2012 13:08:18}   System.DateTime
```

as you can see it doesn't give me milliseconds hence my TimeSpan difference calculation gets thwarted.
Please help.

Comment: Remember that the meaning of `"/"` and `":"` inside your format string depends on the current culture. If the culture is Bengali (India), that is `new CultureInfo("bn-IN")`, the contents of the CVS file will have to be like: `"20-12-2012 13.08.18.980"` for your code to still work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Milliseconds are there. You can verify it using the following code:

```
 Console.Out.WriteLine("current = {0}", current.Millisecond);
```

When you are looking at variable from debugger, it uses `.ToString()` that just does not show milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for this, i realised straight after i posted the question, expanding the debugger and there it was. serves me right for being too hasty.